# Can't add new item to array with value from prev array's item

Tags: postgresql-9.5

column **data** has type **jsonb**

example:

```
"availability": [
    {
      "qty": 31,
       "is_available": false,
      "store": {
        "name": "test_value
      }
    },
```

It's contain array **availability** with one item.

I want to add new item to this array. And get value of node **qty** from first item. And then add this value to second (new) array's item.
As result **availability** will contain 2 items. And nodes **qty** must be equals in both items.

I try this:

```
 WITH subquery AS (
    SELECT 
    id, 
    data #>>'{availability,0,qty}' as qty
    from copy_product
)
UPDATE copy_product 
SET
data = (
 jsonb_set(data, '{availability}', data -> 'availability' || '{
    "qty": subquery.qty,
    "is_available": false,
    "store": {
     "address": null
  }}')
)
```

But I get error:

```
  ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 10: ...onb_set(data, '{availability}', data -> 'availability' || '{
                                                                      ^
DETAIL:  Token "subquery" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {
    "qty": subquery...
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 190
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a sub-query (or even a CTE), you can reference the existing value directly as part of the expression passed to `jsonb_set()`

```
UPDATE copy_product 
  SET data = jsonb_set(data, 
                       '{availability}', 
                       data -> 'availability' 
                        || ('{"qty": '||(data #>>'{availability,0,qty}')||', "is_available": false, "store": {"address": null}}')::jsonb)
```

Alternatively using `jsonb_build_object()`

```
UPDATE copy_product 
  SET data = jsonb_set(data, 
                       '{availability}', 
                       data -> 'availability' || 
                                jsonb_build_object(
                                     'qty', data #>>'{availability,0,qty}', 
                                     'is_available', false, 
                                     'store', jsonb_build_object('address', null)
                                )
```

Comment: I get error: invalid input syntax for type json
                     data -> 'availability' || '{"qty": '|..

Comment: Well there might some formatting errors - try the second version - it's much harder to create invalid JSON when using `jsonb_build_object()`